# Codeigniter Ajax Login issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I'm building an Ajax login with Codeigniter & Jquery... I have a small issue with returning an 'Invalid Login' message and its bugging me.

On the login page I have:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var login = $("#login").val();
        var pass = $("#pass").val();

        $('#login-block').removeBlockMessages().blockMessage('Please wait, cheking login...', {
            type: 'loading'
        });
        $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/login/validate_credentials/", {
            username: login,
            password: pass
        }, function (data) {
            if (data.error) {
                $('#login-block').removeBlockMessages().blockMessage(data.message, {
                    type: 'error'
                });
            } else {
                document.location.href = data.redirect;
            }
        }, "json");
    }
});
```

The `validate()` function simply queries the DB for the username and password matching, if the num_rows = 1 then it returns the users data.

All this works ok when attempting to login, but when I enter a username that doesn't exist I DONT get the 'Incorrect Login' error...

If I use a real username and false password I do get the error.

And if the username and pass are correct it logs in ok.

I just dont understand why it wont display and error when the username doesn't exist?

**Edit**

Here is my Validate() function in the model.

```
function validate() {

    // CHECK LOGIN DETAILS
    $this->db-> select('first_name,last_name,usertype,id,products,mac');
    $this->db-> where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db-> where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get('membership');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = array('usertype' => $row->usertype, 'userid' => $row->id, 'first_name' => $row->first_name, 'last_name' => $row->last_name, 'products' => $row->products, 'mac' = > $row->mac);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: if your model doesnt return any data then its failing...so what are u returning from ur model if there is no matching data/??? try to return `false` when number of rows == 0

Comment: Ive tried adding a return false when num_rows() == 0 but it doesnt make any difference. This cannot be the issue as it returns false and displays an error message to me when the username is correct and the password is false which returns 0 rows, just like it should when the username doesnt exist...

Comment: What comes after the validate()? Do you test it? What do you do with the result in de controller? Try by returning false `if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { ... } else { return false; }` and test it like this in your controller: `if($resultofvalidate === false){ ..return error... } else { ...return success...}`

Comment: Also note that in your example `$row` will be undefined maybe you left it out to simplify, but don't forget to do `$row = $query->first_row();`

Comment: Hi, Yes its tested and returns 1 num_row when the correct data is found and 0 when its not. Just doesnt seem to be working when a username isnt found. Maybe its a CI bug? And yes i just left $row out for the example above, it wasnt relevant to my issue.

Comment: I think the issue is with my Jquery post, it doesnt seem to display the returned error when the username and password are empty even though validate_credentials returns a JSON error.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data.error){
    $('#login-block').html('<p>'+data.message+'</p>);
} else {
    document.location.href = data.redirect;
}
```

Try that.

```
if($query->num_rows()==1)
{
$data2 = array(
    'error' => false,
    'redirect' => base_url().'index.php/site/home/'
    );
```

Okay, I see how about that? On logins you should always be checking that num_rows = 1 by the way, there should never be more than one.

Comment: Sorry, didnt work. Its not the view thats the issue... The view works ok as it displays the error perfecty when the username exists and the password is incorrect. The issue is that the validate(); function in the model only appears to return false when a username exists in the DB, when a username doesnt exist its like its causing an error or something?

Comment: I vaguely remember having this same issue with CI, you should have a return false in the validate too just to be sure the function is getting a result.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with

```
$.getJSON('<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/login/validate_credentials/',{username: login, password: pass}, function(data) {
if(data.error){
$('#login-block').removeBlockMessages().blockMessage(data.message, {type: 'error'});   
} else {
document.location.href = data.redirect;
}
});
```

I needed to use getJSON instead of post.
I had to update the model function to use get instead of post for he variables.
It now works as i had hoped.

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should accept the answer that helped you solve your issue.